# How to check comma string in reverse and replace with dot?

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I have text field Txt__c and it has value like 22,500 and now i wrote one trigger to convert this value to currency field AMOUNT and value should look like 22.500...(this is working fine using my trigger)

But question is : if i have value in text like 22,500,100 then how can i convert this value to 22,500.100 in AMOUNT field ?

Apex Trigger :

```
for(Opportunity op : Trigger.New){
    if(op.Temp_Number__c != null && (op.Temp_Number__c).contains(',')){
        op.Temp_Number__c = op.Temp_Number__c.replace(',','.');
        op.Amount = Decimal.valueOf(op.Temp_Number__c);
    }
}
```

I think i need to check that string in reverse and find comma(,) and replace dot(.) with last comma(,) which should make sense !!

Please suggest the code for reverse checking..

Thanks !!

Please suggest !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the reverse and replaceFirst methods of string to achieve this.

```
String str = '22,500,100';
system.debug('----'+str.reverse().replaceFirst(',', '.').reverse());
output : 22,500.100
```

Comment: Thanks !! it's good solution but here i am stuck again...ERROR : execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.TypeException: Invalid Decimal: 22,500.100

Comment: Code : op.Temp_Number__c = op.Temp_Number__c.reverse().replaceFirst(',','.').reverse();
                op.Amount = decimal.valueOf(op.Temp_Number__c);

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use the manipulated string value as a Decimal you will need to remove the first comma.

```
op.Temp_Number__c = op.Temp_Number__c.reverse().replaceFirst(',','.').reverse();
op.Temp_Number__c = op.Temp_Number__c.replaceFirst(',', '');
op.Amount = decimal.valueOf(op.Temp_Number__c);
System.debug('Decimal Value: ' + op.Amount);
```

> Output: 22500.10